# Importing Project to Spring Boot Parent Pom Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, ssl-certificate, nexus

I was hoping someone could help me out. Some small details will be altered for anonymity.

*Initial problem:**

When importing spring boot project into RAD I get this error:

```
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:3.5.0 from https://nexusrm.<myCompany>.net:8443/repository/<myCompany>-maven/
  was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced.
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:3.5.0 from/to central
  (https://nexusrm.<myCompany>.net:8443/repository/<myCompany>-maven/): PKIX path building failed:
  com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

**Inferred Cause:**

I think my IDE cannot go to my companies nexus repository to get the parent pom file because the repo site uses a self signed certificate (or some other certificate error).

**Workaround:**

After opening my IDE (RAD/eclipse but I also have IntelliJ with same issue). I open the command line (windows 10), navigate/cd to my project, and add `set MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true"`. This allows the Spring Boot project to run, but I have all sorts of other issues that may or may not be related and would like a permanant solution to this to make sure this is not causing issues. (other issues like when I open RAD I get popups saying failure to transfer other things, some projects saying incorrect package declarations, webserver+LDAP authentication stuff, etc)

**Proposed Solution:**

I believe I need to add  the public certificate of the Nexus server to the trust store of the Java running Maven which I learned from this link https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465088-Maven-is-unable-to-connect-to-Nexus-after-configuring-Nexus-to-use-SSL- which says to do this:

1. Get the certificate from the server into a PEM encoded file on your Java client host:

`keytool -printcert -rfc -sslserver example.com > example.pem` (Optional/Advised)`

2. Import the certificate into the default Java truststore location under a relevant alias, using the default truststore password:

`keytool -importcert -file example.pem -alias example.com -storepass changeit -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`

**Main Questions**

I cannot figure out how to do this. I need to know:

1. How to get the certificate (any browser) and how to put it into a PEM encoded file. In regards to the command-
2. I am unsure of what example.com should be and what example.pem should be. I know they are my server and pem file, but
3. Is server just the link of the nexus repo ie `https://nexusrm.<myCompany>.net:8443/repository/<myCompany>-maven/`? And
4. how do I generate this pem file?
5. Do I get the certificate by going to my browser->view certificate->details->copy to file?
6. What do I save the file as?

**Conclusion:**
Thanks so much for taking the time to read, I hope you can tell by my questions that I am new to all of this. It is possible there is a better way to fix this problem, or that this is not the right way to go about it at all it could be a firewall, configuration, or permissions thing, so any advice will be appreciated, just please keep in mind my skill level. I am just setting up my environment for my first software developer job, and trying to learn web applications using spring/spring boot. Please ask if you need more info.

**Additional Info:**
Java version 1.8_0_311 (jdk 1.8_0_311, jre 1.8_0_311)
Apache Maven Version 3.8.3
Particular error on Spring 2.5.5 but similair error on 2.6.0
I am using a Cisco anyconnect vpn

Comment: Do you have a proxy defined in your `settings.xml`?

Comment: @Oliver No. There is nothing configured in my global-level settings.xml. In my user-level settings.xml there is a mirror and profile configured for the nexus repository.

Comment: I solved it.  I don't have enough room in this comment to explain the whole solution step by step, but feel free to reach out if you need it. To summarize, I added maven to system path env. variable, saved my companies truststore.jks, added it as a _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable, used a different settings.xml file which, among other things included a proxy, and added a line to .vmoptions and idea64.exe.vmoptions

Comment: You can answer your own question, Q&A style. Would be useful for others who stumble upon it.